# Symfony 4 Sonata User Bundle Installation

Tags: sonata-user-bundle, symfony4

I followed all instructions from installation guide but still
have this error during installation of Sonata User Bundle on Symfony 4 application:

```
Column name `id` referenced for relation from Application\Sonata\UserBundle\Entity\User towards Sonata\UserBundle\Entity\BaseGroup does not exist.
```

My config is totally same as in [installation guide](https://sonata-project.org/bundles/user/4-x/doc/reference/installation.html).

Didn't find any solutions on stackoverflow or anywhere else.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Finally I found the solution, but it took some time, so I want to post it here for everyone who encounter this problem.

Adding this code to config (e.g. `sonata_core.yaml`):

```
sonata_user:
    class:
        user:               Application\Sonata\UserBundle\Entity\User
        group:              Application\Sonata\UserBundle\Entity\Group
```

and changing values of `user_class` and `group_class` in config (e.g. `fos_user.yaml`) solves problem:

```
fos_user:
    db_driver:      orm
    firewall_name:  main
    user_class:     Application\Sonata\UserBundle\Entity\User
    from_email:
        address:        noreply@example.com
        sender_name:    John Doe

    group:
        group_class:   Application\Sonata\UserBundle\Entity\Group
        group_manager: sonata.user.orm.group_manager

    service:
        user_manager: sonata.user.orm.user_manager
```

There is nothing about this in [installation guide](https://sonata-project.org/bundles/user/4-x/doc/reference/installation.html), I found it in [advanced configuration](https://sonata-project.org/bundles/user/4-x/doc/reference/advanced_configuration.html) chapter.

Hope this helps someone.

Comment: It helped me to pass one step, 
The documentation does say noting about the Custum User bundle.
Thanks.